# Rails undefined method `<model_name>_index_path' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting trouble using form_for. Rails is launching the following error:

```
undefined method `<model_name>_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x9f6b4dc>:0x9c381c0>
```

in this exact line of denuncia.html.erb (**replacing @denuncia with Denuncia.new won't work**):

```
<%= form_for @denuncia do |f| %>
```

Here is all the code:

***routes.rb***

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'welcome#index'
  get 'form' => 'form#denuncia'
  resources :form
```

***form_controller.rb***

```
class FormController < ApplicationController
    def denuncia
       @denuncia = Denuncia.new
    end
end
```

***denuncia.html.erb***

```
<%= form_for @denuncia do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :onde %>
    <%= f.input :quando %>
    <%= f.input :descricao %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This seems very strange, because the model is being initialized (or it seems to be). Thanks in advance to you all for the help! (:

Comment: Can you post your `rake routes` output?

Comment: Where should the form post to?

Comment: I assume <model_name> is a stand-in for the actual model name or is that the exact error code you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

As the model is `Denuncia`, just having `form_for @denuncia` rails looks at the model and will try and go to `denuncias_path` which isn't defined.  Resources are usually pluralised so if you change to `resources :forms` then changing to this should work

```
<%= form_for @denuncia, url: forms_path do |f| %>
```

Sorry, not sure what the path would be for `resources :form` but you can `rake routes` to find out.

If you change to `resources forms` you'll need to make changes to pluralise the form directory to forms and `form_controller` to `forms_controller`

Comment: from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

`<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>`
is perfectly ok, but it would normally go to post_path which is the create path not post_index_path.

Comment: Baloo is right. If @denuncia object is an instance of Denuncia model then rails by default will look for denuncias_path, unless you specify another path as Baloo did. These are all parts of Rails conventions, which are very handy when you know how it works. You can read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form